# How to get the value of multidimensional array based on the ID

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array, i display all of the values in a table using foreach loop. in that table i have an view profile (a href=). what i want to do is to get the array and pass it to another page and display the value of the array based on the id

```
<?php include_once('fake_db.php'); ?>

<--index.php-->

<div class="widget-body">
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Action</th>        
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php foreach($employees as $key => $value){ ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $value['name']?></td>
            <td><?= $value['position']; ?></td>
            <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?= $key; ?>">View Profile</a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
</div>

<-- profile.php -->
<h3>Employee Profile : Employee Name</h3>
<a href="index.php">Back to Employee List</a>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name </td>
        <td>Employee Position</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>

            <td></td>
            <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<--fake_db.php-->
<?php

$employees = array
             (
               1 => array("name" => 'Jason Alipala', "employee_id" => 'G1001-05', 'position' => 1),
               2 => array("name" => 'Bryann Revina', "employee_id" => 'G1009-03', 'position' => 2),
               3 => array("name" => 'Jeniel Mangahis', "employee_id" => 'G1009-04', 'position' => 2),
               4 => array("name" => 'Arjay Bussala', "employee_id" => 'G1009-05', 'position' => 3),
               5 => array("name" => 'Ronnel Ines', "employee_id" => 'G1002-06', 'position' => 3)
             );

$emp_positions = array_count_values(array_column($employees, 'position'));

$positions = array(1 => 'TL', 2 => 'Programmer', 3 => 'Converter');


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace `profile.php` to following.

```php
<?php include_once('fake_db.php'); 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $employee = $employees[$id]
    ?>
<h3>Employee Profile : Employee Name</h3>
<a href="index.php">Back to Employee List</a>
<table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Name </td>
        <td>Employee Position</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>

            <td><?php echo $employee['name'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $employee['position'] ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How about display all the list

Answer (score 1):

In the profile.php code it as below, I have put the selected employees information array to `selected_employees` array for ease.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET["id"])):
    $selected_employee=$employees[$_GET["id"]];
    ?>

    <h1>Is Set</h1>
    <h3>Employee Profile : <?= $selected_employee["name"]; ?></h3>
    <a href="index.php">Back to Employee List</a>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name <?= $selected_employee["name"]; ?></td>
                <td>Employee Position: <?= $selected_employee["position"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get you id from your with $_GET[•id'] 
 and you can check ur id by isset if pass or not...
if(isset($_GET['id'])

thn pass that id to your database or if you passing key of array ..pass that key to array

Answer (score 0):

You can take @Khiev' s answer. But if you don't want to include the data file twice then you can follow this procedure-

```
    <?php include_once('fake_db.php'); ?>

    <--index.php-->

    <div class="widget-body">
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Action</th>        
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach($employees as $key => $value){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $value['name']?></td>
                <td><?= $value['position']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="profile.php?id=<?= rawurlencode(json_encode($value)); ?>">View Profile</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
    </div>

  And in the `profile.php` file grab the `id` variable via `$_GET` variable.

<?php 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $employee = json_decode(rawurldecode($id), true);
?>
    <h3>Employee Profile : Employee Name</h3>
    <a href="index.php">Back to Employee List</a>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Name </td>
               <td>Employee Position</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $employee['name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $employee['position'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```